Using stochastic differential equation for modeling quantum errors
The evolution of a quantum state under continuous measurement can be described by a stochastic differential equation (SDE) of the form
$$d\psi(t) = -iH\psi(t)dt - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^n L_j^{\dagger}L_j \psi(t)dt + \sum_{j=1}^n L_j\psi(t)dW_j. \tag{1}$$
Here, $dW_j$ are Wiener stochastic increments of $n$ independent Wiener processes $W_j$, and $L_j$ are Lindblad operators.
From reading the literature this and this, I got the impression that the major use case of SDEs is continuous weak measurements. Under this interpretation, the increments $dW_j$ are actual observed measurement outcomes that serve as updates to the quantum state. The update is done with the terms $L_j\psi(t)dW_j$.

I would like to know if SDE in (1) could be used to describe the evolution of a quantum state under perturbances and errors introduced by the environment, which weakly interacts with the primary system. What must we assume to use (1) for statistically modelling environment perturbations and errors?

One of the stack users provides a great explanation. The explanation states that $dW$ is used when an observer keeps track of measurements to update the state. However, I was hoping that $dW$ could be used to model random environment errors.

The difference between a "measurement" and an "interaction with the environment" is essentially what the environment does with that information. From the point of view of the system they are indistinguishable. This method is used pretty routinely in modelling open quantum systems, particularly as a numerical Monte Carlo method, where it is known as the "quantum jump" or "quantum trajectories" method, see this review

@BySymmetry thank you for the reference.
